# Jump to next view controller with out back button

Tags: ios

I have a login page when a user login with user name or password then it jump to next view controller. But with back navigation, I want jump to next view controller but without back button navigation.

For this work i write code

```
HomeViewController *pushWithSlot=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:pushWithSlot animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of them to hide back button

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

OR

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Comment: Give this a try self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];